# Drawing Hexagon Using Java error

Tags: java, graphics

i written a code to draw a hexagon. First i plot the 6 points using this formula : 
(x + r*cos(i*2*pi/6), y + r*sin(i*2*pi/6))
then after i plot these points i tried to match between the points using Bresnham's Algorithm for drawing lines which i had implemented it in a method.
Unfortunately the Code doesn't work successfully and i get this instead of the hexagon. I think there is an error with Bresnham's algorithm implementation. In addition, I tried to plot each point alone but it wont work.
If anyone can help me?

[image]

Also this is my Code :

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class LinesDrawingExample extends JFrame {

    public LinesDrawingExample() {
        super("Lines Drawing Demo");

        //Dimension screenSize=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    void drawLines(Graphics g , int x,int y) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);


        g2d.drawLine(x, y, x,y);


        //g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(59.2d, 99.8d, 419.1d, 99.8d));

       // g2d.draw(new Line2D.Float(21.50f, 132.50f, 459.50f, 132.50f));

    }

    public void getvalue(Graphics g,double x1,double y1 ,double x2,double y2){









        int x=(int)x1;
        int y=(int)y1;
        int deltax=(int)x2-(int)x1;
        int deltay=(int)y2-(int)y1;
        int twodeltay=2*deltay;
        int var1=twodeltay-(2*deltax);
        int p=twodeltay-deltax;
        drawLines(g,x,y);


        while(x<x2)
        {
            drawLines(g,x,y);

            if(p>0)
            {
            y=y+1;
            p=p+twodeltay-(2*deltax);

            }
            else
            {
                p=p+twodeltay;
            }
            x++;


}
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        double r=50;
        double pi=3.14;

        int [] xval =new int [6];
        int [] yval=new int [6];

        int x=100,y=100;

       for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
   getvalue(g,x + r*cos(i*2*pi/6), y + r*sin(i*2*pi/6),x + r*cos(i*2*pi/6),y + r*cos(i*2*pi/6));
   xval[i]=(int)(x + r*cos(i*2*pi/6));
   yval[i]=(int)(y + r*sin(i*2*pi/6));
       }


           getvalue(g,xval[4],yval[4],xval[5],yval[5]);
           getvalue(g,xval[2],yval[2],xval[1],yval[1]);


             getvalue(g,xval[3],yval[3],xval[2],yval[2]);
              getvalue(g,xval[3],yval[3],xval[3],yval[3]);
               getvalue(g,xval[4],yval[4],xval[4],yval[4]);
              getvalue(g,xval[5],yval[5],xval[5],yval[5]);









    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LinesDrawingExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Override `paintComponent(g)`, not `paint(g)`.

Comment: @user3437460 i tried to override paintComponent(g) but it is not included in methods to be override.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were drawing on the JFrame.  Never draw on a JFrame.  Always draw on a JPanel.

Here's the GUI.

[image: Hexagon]

Here are the major changes I made.

1. I moved the creation of the hexagon into its own class, Hexagon.  That way, you can create a List of Hexagons if you want.
2. I moved the creation of the drawing panel into its own class, DrawingPanel.  That way, I have a GUI view class that draws the hexagon, and a GUI model class that generates the hexagons.  A nice, clean separation of concerns.
3. This left the JFrame code and the instantiation of a Hexagon object in the constructor of the LinesDrawingExample class.

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LinesDrawingExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3775690273871048733L;

    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    public LinesDrawingExample() {
        super("Lines Drawing Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Hexagon hexagon = new Hexagon(new Point(250, 250), 200);

        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(hexagon);
        add(drawingPanel);

        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LinesDrawingExample();
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5701311351092275287L;

        private Hexagon hexagon;

        public DrawingPanel(Hexagon hexagon) {
            this.hexagon = hexagon;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawPolygon(hexagon.getHexagon());
        }
    }

    public class Hexagon {
        private final int radius;

        private final Point center;

        private final Polygon hexagon;

        public Hexagon(Point center, int radius) {
            this.center = center;
            this.radius = radius;
            this.hexagon = createHexagon();
        }

        private Polygon createHexagon() {
            Polygon polygon = new Polygon();

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                int xval = (int) (center.x + radius
                        * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6D));
                int yval = (int) (center.y + radius
                        * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6D));
                polygon.addPoint(xval, yval);
            }

            return polygon;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public Point getCenter() {
            return center;
        }

        public Polygon getHexagon() {
            return hexagon;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't override `paint(g)`. Override `paintComponent(g)` instead. You can use a loop to plots all the points needed for a polygon.

Plot the points and create a Polygon object, then draw the polygon object:

[image]

```
public class DrawPolyPanel extends JPanel{
    public DrawPolyPanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);            
        Polygon p = new Polygon();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            p.addPoint((int) (100 + 50 * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6)),
              (int) (100 + 50 * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6)));        
        g.drawPolygon(p);    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawPoly");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new DrawPolyPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```